# Show X axis ticks between bars for a histogram

Tags: reactjs, recharts

I have a Rechart bar chart that represents a histogram, currently the X axis ticks are in the middle of the bars.

[image]

I would like them to be between the bars rather than in the middle of the bars.

[image]

I have a code sample of what I have so far, but I cannot figure out how to shift the X axis ticks.

https://codesandbox.io/embed/agitated-water-iv0sj

Answer (score 3):

Try setting the axis scale to "band": `<XAxis scale="band" />`. I forked your codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/new-field-u5oze

Comment: scale="band" appears to have stopped working as of recharts 2.x.x, https://github.com/recharts/recharts/issues/2742 ?

Answer (score 2):

I found a workaround today for this, and commented on the issue linked above: https://github.com/recharts/recharts/issues/2742#issuecomment-1516920595  The upshot is to render *two* `XAxis` elements, one for arranging the data and the other for rendering the ticks.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Ben Lerner's two-axis solution did it for me, although I couldn't get `scale="band"` to work.

Instead, just a regular number type axis, with a fixed domain and tick count. In this case, something like:

```
<BarChart data={data}>
    <XAxis dataKey="elementCount" hide />
    <XAxis xAxisId="ticks" type="number" domain={[0, 5]} tickCount={6} />
    <YAxis allowDecimals={false} />
    ...
</BarChart>
```